# Turn Cross Apply opensjson results into columns

Tags: sql, arrays, json, sql-server

We have a table that has a field with some json.
using cross apply I was able to turn those pairs into columns:

```
select [mytable].ID,[mytable].[IndexFields],  jsonvalues.[Key], jsonvalues.[Value]

from [mytable]

cross APPLY OPENJSON([mytable].[IndexFields])
WITH
([Key] nvarchar(255) ,
[Value] nvarchar(255) ) as jsonValues
order by [mytable].ID
```

[image: Result]

So how do I turn this into something like :

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know all of the possible key names (firstname, lastname, MyChoice, etc.) in advance? Or does it need to adjust for every new key that gets added? Also please post table structure and sample data as inserts (e.g. using [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019) with the right version of SQL Server selected) as opposed to pictures.

Comment: Have a look into conditional aggregation or pivoting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the limited set of possible key names in advance, you can just use `PIVOT`:

```
;WITH src AS 
(
  select [mytable].ID,[mytable].[IndexFields],
    jsonvalues.[Key], jsonvalues.[Value]
    from dbo.[mytable]
    cross APPLY OPENJSON([mytable].[IndexFields])
    WITH
    ([Key] nvarchar(255) , 
    [Value] nvarchar(255) ) as jsonValues
)
SELECT * FROM src
  PIVOT (
    MAX(Value) FOR [Key] IN 
    ([firstname],[lastname],[MyChoice],[Optional Coverages])
  ) AS p
ORDER BY src.ID;
```

But you can't write a `PIVOT` if you don't know all those possible values up front. So it's a wee bit more complicated and requires dynamic SQL (I wrote [an article about dynamic PIVOT here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)):

```
DECLARE @keys nvarchar(max);

SELECT @keys = STRING_AGG('[' + STRING_ESCAPE([Key], 'json') + ']', ',')
FROM 
(
  SELECT j.[Key]
    FROM dbo.mytable AS t
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.IndexFields)
    WITH
    (
      [Key]   nvarchar(255),
      [Value] nvarchar(255) 
    ) AS j
    GROUP BY j.[Key]
) AS x;

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
;WITH src AS 
(
  SELECT t.ID, t.IndexFields, j.[Key], j.[Value]
    FROM dbo.mytable AS t
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.IndexFields)
    WITH
    (
      [Key]   nvarchar(255),
      [Value] nvarchar(255) 
    ) AS j
)
SELECT * FROM src
PIVOT (MAX(Value) FOR [Key] IN (' + @keys + N')) AS p
ORDER BY ID;';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e8c070a43be41bbaa72ec89fe0b951b6)